# How to destroy object by tag in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I made a bullet that is spawd on hiting "w"

and these is in the bullet script:

```
 function OnCollisionEnter(collision: Collision) {
  if (collision.gameObject.tag == "enemy"){
          Destroy(gameObject); 
   }
}
```

I added the tag "enemy" to the enemy object
but it apears not to be entering the function
i want to destroy the bullet on hiting. I realy dont get what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.attach the **script** to your **bullet** 
2.**both** GameObjects must have **colliders**
3.one of the colliders must have a **non-kinematic rigidbody** attached
4.check the **collision matrix** to see if collision between their **layers** are enabled
5.**meshCollider** wont collide with meshCollider